# rpm spec Requires wildcard in package name

Tags: wildcard, rpm-spec

I'm creating an RPM that has a requirement on another package that has the version number in the middle of the package name.

For instance `softwarepackage10.1-util-10.1.1.x86_64.rpm`. The name would change with the next release, for instance `softwarepackage11.2-util-11.2.1.x86_64.rpm`.

I have no control over the other package.

I need to specify a `Requires` line for this package with any version `>= 10`.

Can I specify as follows?:

`Requires: softwarepackage*-util >= 10`

Answer (score 3):

No, it will not work with a wildcard like you've mentioned. When you will try to install the package, it will result in something like the following:

```
 ]# rpm -ivh mypackage.rpm --test
 error: Failed dependencies:
       softwarepackage-*-util is needed by mypackage
```

`softwarepackage-*` should be named more appropriately, but if it is a constraint, then in the rpm spec file, you can use define.

```
 % define softwarepackage_major_version 10
 % define softwarepackage_minor_version 1
```

Alternative, you can use a binary that softwarepackage*-util provides, and use that instead and let the package manager to resolve the version and conflicts.

```
  Requires: /usr/bin/binary-from-softwarepackge
```

Comment: Could you please expand on how you would make subsequent use of the #define macros?